# Use Notepad++ styles with Sublime Text 2

Tags: notepad++, sublime-text-2, highlighting

Is it possible to use notepad++ syntax themes/styles with sublime text 2?

If so, how do I do this.

I code COBOL programs, and love some of the features in sublime. But it lacks the syntax highlighting that is available in Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch - you are somewhat stuffed there.

A quick review shows no existing Sublime or Textmate (Sublime supports the use of Textmate bundles) highlighters for COBOL. In fact, there seem to be very few COBOL editors around.

My only suggestion is to examine the COBOL highlighter file for Notepad++ and manually convert it to Sublime's XML format.

Comment: You seem to be right. And after a quick look at the code involved to do that. I don't see any time to do it. I know COBOL is an old lang. But I'm young and still see how widely it's used and maintained in my work place. N++ came out with the syntax highlighting for it in the past 2-3 years. Maybe sublime will too. (thought I don't count on it).

Comment: I feel for you. If it makes you feel any better (it wont ;) I started my professional programming life on COBOL on IBM mainframes. It would be worth putting out a request on the [Sublime Forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) to see if anyone can help.

Comment: If you use "package control" some COBOL syntax highlighting exists.